# How to crossfade between 2 images on iPhone using Core Animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm doing this to learn how to work with Core Animation animatable properties on iPhone (not to learn how to crossfade images, per se).

Reading similar questions on SO leads me to believe it can be done by animating the **.contents** property of the **UIImageView's** **layer** like so:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage2.png"];

self.imageView.image = image1;
[self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
crossFade.duration = 5.0;
self.imageView.layer.contents = image2;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
```

Did I get a detail wrong or is this not possible.

**Update:** the above code produces a blank UIImageView. When I change this line:

```
self.imageView.layer.contents = image2.CGImage;
```

...I can see the image now but it does not fade in, it just appears instantly.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
crossFade.duration = 5.0;
crossFade.fromValue = image1.CGImage;
crossFade.toValue = image2.CGImage;
[self.imageView.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
```

Note that the animation is independent of the actual values/contents of the UIImageView. Therefore you'll need to

```
self.imageView.image = image2;
```

... to set the final result for your image.

Comment: It works, crossfading the image. How do you suppress the compiler warning "Passing argument 1 of 'setFromValue:' from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: .fromValue and .toValue expect a pointer to an Objective-C object, not a pointer to a CFType like CGImageRef is. Therefore you can do this:

    crossFade.fromValue = (id)(image1.CGImage);
    crossFade.toValue = (id)(image2.CGImage);

Comment: Can something similar be done for text/background colors, on a UIButton for example?

Answer (score 65):

I found this somewhere - it works great.

Swift

```
UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 0.33, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
      imageView.image = image
}, completion: nil)
```

Objc

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.33f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.imageview.image = toImage;
                } completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 22):

```
extension UIImageView
{
    func mySetImage(image:UIImage)
    {
        guard let currentImage = self.image where currentImage != image else { return }
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.duration = 0.3
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "ImageFade")
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: super simple and super effective! thanks. IMO the best approach is to extend UIImageView and override setImage with this sugar

Comment: Agreed. This is a much simpler solution.

Comment: The compare for the two images is potentially very expensive, I don't recommend converting two images to PNG just to compare if they are the same.

Comment: this is the best answer IMO

Comment: @steipete This has become exceptionally apparent when using this method for a `UITableViewCell` imageView, where it may be called 10+ times and causes a massive delay.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=false;
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgview.frame=CGRectMake(30,90, img.size.width, img.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:imgview];
[self animateImages];
}
- (void)animateImages
{
static int count = 0;
NSArray *animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"images (1).jpeg"]];
UIImage *image = [animationImages objectAtIndex:(count % [animationImages count])];

[UIView transitionWithView:imgview
                  duration:2.0f // animation duration
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    imgview.image = image;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self animateImages];
                    count++;
                }];
```

}

Comment: Nice code for a cross fade image rotator. Works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in swift

```
let image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "someImage1")!;
let image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "someImage2")!;
let crossFade:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents");
crossFade.duration = 5.0;
crossFade.fromValue = image1.CGImage;
crossFade.toValue = image2.CGImage;
imageView.layer.addAnimation(crossFade, forKey:"animateContents");
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to just use two `UIImageView`s on top of each other.  The one on top has the image1, and on bottom is image2:

```
- (void) crossfade {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    imageView1.alpha = !imageView1.alpha;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

That will fade between the two images whenever you call it.  If you want to just do a single fade and remove the first image after you're done:

```
- (void) crossfade {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:imageView1];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    imageView1.alpha = 0
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**Edit:**

If you're looking for a reason why your code doesn't work, it's because you're just setting the property to the new image, then adding a useless animation.  `CABasicAnimation` has the `fromValue` and `toValue` that need to be set, then add that animation to the layer, and it should do the animation.  Don't set the contents manually.

Comment: You're answer is appreciated but I'm trying to learn about CA animatable properties and the syntax of using key paths rather than how to cross fade images per se. Do you know what I'm doing wrong in my code sample?