# background flashes during image swap cross disolve, CATransition

Tags: objective-c, catransition, visual-glitch

Currently I have a CATransistion that should swap out the _backgroundImageView.image with a new one.  It works great... And works quickly, however the previous image will glitch during this transition randomly... Aka flash the full image for one frame somewhere in the duration of the transition and then finish the transition.

Here is the code:

```
[CATransaction begin];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.delegate = self;
[transition setValue:@"swipe" forKey:@"tag"];
[_backgroundImageView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

 _backgroundImageView.image = [_backgroundImages objectAtIndex:pageControl.currentPage];
[CATransaction commit];
```

If I add this before the code then the glitch doesnt happen but other UI stuff gets choppy because the image comparison seems to block the main thread (which it has to as the animation is a main thread thing too)

```
if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(_backgroundImageView.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([_backgroundImages objectAtIndex:pageControl.currentPage])]) {
    return;
}
```

BTW flickering doesn't happen on the device.... at least so far I can see... so maybe this question is moot... I have seen crashes during transitions... but that might be another issue.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353744/1318525

Comment: I did. But the same issue with the representation and flickering

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to try loading the two images into memory before the animation. The way you've written the code, the second image isn't pulled from the array until it's needed. Load the two images into separate variables before the animation starts and do the cross fade animation between them.

Comment: Is this still reproducible?