# How to control crossfade between two UIImage's Without Animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, cross-fade

There are a lot of posts about crossfade of `UIImage`s using an animation.  But I can't find how to control the crossfade **without animation**, but instead by myself; for example with a parameter between `0.0` and `1.0` that controls the amount of crossfade.

I could put two `UIImageView`s behind each other and control the `alpha` (top one going from `1.0` to `0.0`, and the bottom one at `1.0`), but that's not a proper crossfade AFAIK.

To make it more graphic: On screen there's a slider that gives a value between `0.0` and `1.0`, above it is an image.  What I want is to crossfade between the initially shown image (when slider is `0.0`) and another image (which if fully visible when slider is `1.0`).  So, when you'd slowly move the slider, you'd see the other image slowly appear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to crossfade between 2 images on iPhone using Core Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550206/how-to-crossfade-between-2-images-on-iphone-using-core-animation)

Comment: @Bamsworld I don't want the animation to control the amount of cross-fade; I want to control it myself using a parameter.  Clear?

Comment: @Wain I don't see no parameter that I can set between `0.0` and `1.0`, which controls the amount of crossfade.  This is NOT a duplicate of what you say.

Comment: If you use two UIImageViews with clear backgrounds and vary the alpha channels from 0-1, 1-0, you should get very close to the effect you're looking for.  I've found it works better if there's a black background behind both of them.  It's perhaps not a `true` crossfade, but comes close enough for most usages.

Comment: @David Sounds very good, I'm going to try that.  Please put as answer and I will reward you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use two UIImageViews with clear backgrounds and vary the alpha channels from 0-1, 1-0, you should get very close to the effect you're looking for. I've found it works better if there's a black background behind both of them. It's perhaps not a true crossfade, but comes close enough for most usages.

Comment: This works perfectly, and indeed black at the back looks best. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the image view `alpha` approach. How correct this is depends on the effect you're looking for. Using a value between 0 and 1 makes this approach relatively simple and is the obvious choice.

You could also look at rendering both images into a context and using `CGContextSetBlendMode`, possibly with `kCGBlendModeMultiply`, to combine the images. No parameters are available with this so you would still need to change the alpha of the rendering to get an acceptable merge / fade.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that I used CATransition animations: 
This a snippet from an old code

```
CATransition *fadeTransition = [CATransition animation];
fadeTransition.duration = 1.0f;
fadeTransition.type = kCATransitionFade;
fadeTransition.endProgress = 0.75;
[imageView setImage:/*YourImage*/];
[imageView.layer addAnimation:fadeTransition forKey:nil];
```

With -`endProgress` property you can set the end before it completes, but I have not a clear idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't helpful, but I don't think this is the right attitude to get more help. Cheers