# Animate UIButton state to fade in and fade out on tap

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want have a `UIbutton` fade into its highlighted state when tapped then fade out when the user removes their finger from the button. I tried doing this with `transitionWithView` but that only works for fading out of the highlighted state when the user removes their finger.

Here is My code. Thanks.

```
  [UIView transitionWithView:view duration:.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:nil completion:nil];
```

[image: highlighted]
[image: normal]

Answer (score 3):

First make a new SubClass of UIButton, in my example i called it "MyButton".

And use the:

touchesBegan

touchesEnded

touchesMoved

For achieving that fade that you are looking for, like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyButton : UIButton

@end



#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
          self.viewForBaselineLayout.alpha = 0;
    }];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.viewForBaselineLayout.alpha = 1;
    }];

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.viewForBaselineLayout.alpha = 1;
    }];

}
@end
```

And finally use it in your UIVIewController:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    MyButton *button = [[MyButton alloc]init];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [button setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"HelloThere" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: ok, i just did this but when the button is tapped it disappears and does not display the highlighted state image. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly would you like you fade? the title?

Comment: I would like to fade between button states

Comment: What i want is instead of just going into the highlighted state of a button press have a fade transition into the highlighted state and then when u remove ur finger fade back to the normal state

Comment: What is your highlighted effect? color change? fade? animation? You just need to override the "- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated", and change the "self.viewForBaselineLayout.alpha = 0;" to: "   [self setHighlighted:YES];"

Comment: i added the exact mockup images to the question.

Comment: so i did that but that just changes the button to a highlighted state and doesn't do any fading

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you are actually looking for, and if i'm mistaken please current me. But you cannot animate an image (incase you use Image Processing and you probably not looking for something so complex ), to an image, you can make a simple fading effect. Or you can change your Highlighted to a different background color instead of a different image, and then achieve that effect that you are seeking for.

Comment: Im not trying to animate anything I just want have a transition between states(a fade).

Comment: so when u tap a button it fades in to the highlighted state and when you lift ur finger it fades back to the normal state

Comment: If you have two images, and you need one to "fade" it to the ether, that is not a normal "fade". A fade is when one image is fading to alpa 0. Would you like the first image to fade to 0, and then the second one to fade to 1? or do you need one image to fade to the ether?  because these are two separate thing

Comment: If you are looking for one image to another, it is called "Cross fading" and you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550206/how-to-crossfade-between-2-images-on-iphone-using-core-animation

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    button.highlighted = YES;
}];
```

Comment: this doesn't fade it in or out though